# What does Molecular Orbital Theory allow you to predict?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, reactivity

Molecular Orbital theory reveals the outcome when two atomic orbitals overlap. Almost all of the time we draw a Y axis with the notation of energy that can be described using electron volt units (eV). However I don't recall in university lectures or in textbooks any actual values associated with either atomic orbital or molecular orbital states. For example when two Hydrogen atomic orbitals come together. Are there actual energy values associated with these and if so how would they relate to reactivity. In relation to this does Molecular Orbital theory allow to predict reactivity of common nucleophiles and electrophiles seen in Organic Chemistry.

Thanks

Comment: It is a long story. But yes, as far one can go with calculations. But one can predict a lot of properties, at least in principle. First of all energetic levels to be seen via spectroscopy. *note that even the principle predicts a degree of approssimazioni, as orbital are solved for mono electronic systems.

Comment: For organic chemistry just have a look at Woodward Hoffman rules and Theory of Frontier Orbitals.

Comment: For the specific question of how energy values are associated with orbitals, look up photoelectron spectroscopy and also the basic concept of the Schrodinger Equation, even if the details of the math are beyond what you have learned.

Comment: When you say the Schrodinger Equation are you implying the Wave function of a atomic orbital and how we can apply the potential energy operator to get a value? Would this also relate to the particle in a box idea?